# Google Ads Clicks = Analytics Paid + Organic?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

We're using google analytics through tag manager and google ads to acquire leads. We noticed something we cannot explain and have begun doubting the validity of our data in general:

For a given month, we look into google ads and see a total of say 1000 clicks. In analytics, we can see some "paid" access and some "organic". The supposedly strange part is, that clicks = paid + organic. That is at least roughly the case, and varies 5% up or down.

As far as we understand, "organic" is only when someone uses a search engine and clicks on us but not on an Ad we published but the "organic" search result. This is unlikely since our ranking sucks hard at this time and we could find ourselves on page 10.000 even if we wanted to. So how can organic we related to the number or Ads clicks, when organic is exactly the opposite of Ads does?